# regular pentagon to find the sine and cosine of one-fifth of a turn

Tags: geometry

I am reading the [Measurement by Paul Lockhart](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0674284380).
I absolutely enjoy the book and absolutely do not cross over sections until i either workout or find answers to the questions posed. I am currently stuck on the following question.

Part 1, section 20, page 132, the questions is

"can you use a regular pentagon to find the sine and cosine of one-fifth of a turn ?"

I can see how one can extend the edges and form a 36-72-72 isosceles triangle but from there i do not know how to continue. I am hoping the answers should be simple enough that we do not need a calculator and we consider a unit pentagon whose diagonal is golden ratio.

Comment: If you know the sides are 1 and the diagonals are $(\sqrt5+1)/2$, then you should be able to find $\cos72^{\circ}$ using the Law of Cosines.

Comment: Did that help any?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: cool thanks. i was looking for answer with a right angle triangle. but thanks yes law of cosines makes sense :)

Comment: why is asking a question down vote ? im curious :) There are no dump questions.

Comment: Well, the downvote seems to have gotten your attention, after you abandoned the question for two days, so it's not all bad.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted yesterday, bicep?

Comment: Earth to bicep: Come in, please.

Comment: Please remind me not to bother with any questions you may post in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Draw an altitude of the pentagon, say, from the vertex $A$ to the opposite side $BC$, meeting that side at $D$. Then $ABD$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse $AB$ of length $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$, the golden ratio, and side $BD$ of length one-half, so the other side, $AD$, is, by Pythagoras, of length $\sqrt{\phi^2-(1/4)}$. Angle $ABD$ is one-fifth of a turn (also known as 72 degrees, or $2\pi/5$ radians), so the sine of this angle is opposite over hypotenuse, which is  $AD/AB$, which is $\sqrt{\phi^2-(1/4)}/\phi$, and the cosine is adjacent over hypotenuse, $BD/AB$, $(1/2)/\phi$.

Comment: We have $4\phi^2-1=(2\phi+1)(2\phi-1)=(2\phi+1)\sqrt5$, and using the relation $\phi^2=\phi+1$ we can prove $2\phi+1=\phi^3$. So $2\sin(72°)=\sqrt{\phi\sqrt5}$.